# How to get red of these markers on pdf

Tags: tables, floats, equations, pdf

I was using Latex to write my report and whene I open the pdf generated I had (equations, Notations, list of figures, list of tables...) marked in red or green as shown in the image. How can I get rid of these markers.
Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was solved adding:           
          \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} to the \documentclass